# Term paper and field work ideas

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Can we post questions asking for ideas on term papers and field work on specific topics? I didn't find any related open question. The [one](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/46278/simple-computational-biology-project-for-ap-biology-class-ideas) that I found was closed and was tagged 'opinion based'.

Comment: What is "Termpaper"? Is it your examination? If yes, then the question would be a homework. You should fulfill all requirements for a homework question for it to be considered on-topic. I'm sure you know the rules. In any cases you cannot *ask* for ideas because that qualifies as opinion-seeking; it would be *primarily opinion based*.

Comment: Termpaper is a long essay prepared after reading different papers on a specific topic. Yes it is a part of examination. Even if I fulfill the criteria of homework question can such questions still find a place in Biology stack exchange?

Comment: Depends on how you ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We get questions looking for ideas for science projects at all levels, from grade school teachers to university students, and these questions are almost all closed as either "Primarily Opinion-Based" or "Too Broad", depending on the question and how the close-voters interpret it. Questions asking for ideas for term papers (it's two words, not one) or field work would be just as off-topic.

Stack Exchange questions are supposed to be answerable based on facts or specific expertise, not opinions or vague suggestions. These types of questions actively encourage opinion-based answers and spam, which is why they are not allowed.